# Azure SQL Data Warehouse: No catalog entry found for partition ID <id> in database <id>. The metadata is inconsistent. Run DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am working on moving stored procedures from an on-prem SQL Server database to an Azure SQL Data Warehouse (ASDW).  Throughout the process I have had to work around a few missing features - time consuming but not impossible.  One thing I have had to do is replace CTE's followed by MERGE statements with temp tables followed by UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statements (since CTE's cannot be followed by these statements).  At the beginning of each SP I check for the temp tables and delete them if they exist.

Today, I created another stored procedure in the ASDW without any temp tables (no updates/inserts/deletes so I left the CTE's in there), it "compiled", and I was able to run it without issue (returned an empty result set, as there is no data yet).  I created another SP after this, and when I went to execute it, I got the following error:

> ...No catalog entry found for partition ID (id) in database 26.  The metadata is inconsistent. Run DBCC CHECKDB to check for a metadata corruption...

I then went back to the first SP that I mentioned, and it gave me the same error, even though it had previously run without flaw.

I tried running DBCC CHECKDB as instructed but alas, it is not supported/doesn't work.

I dug around a lot, and what I ended up doing was scaling my database from 100DWU's to 500DWU's.  I am at 0.16% of my database storage size limit, and there is barely any data anywhere (total DB size is <300MB).

Is there an explanation for this?  If not, I can't in good conscience use this platform in a production environment.

Full error:

```
Msg 110802, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail.
Details: Exception: Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Workers.DmsSqlNativeException,
 Message: SqlNativeBufferReader.Run, error in OdbcExecuteQuery: SqlState:
 42000, NativeError: 608, 'Error calling: SQLExecDirect(this->GetHstmt(), (SQLWCHAR *)statementText, SQL_NTS), SQL return code: -1 | SQL Error Info: 
SrvrMsgState: 1, SrvrSeverity: 16,  Error <1>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]No catalog entry found for partition ID
72057594047758336 in database 36. The metadata is inconsistent. Run DBCC
CHECKDB to check for a metadata corruption. | Error calling: pReadConn-
>ExecuteQuery(statementText, bufferFormat) | state: FFFF, number: 134148, 
active connections: 100', Connection String: Driver={pdwodbc};APP=TypeC01-
DmsNativeReader:DB196\mpdwsvc (2504)-    ODBC;Trusted_Connection=yes;AutoTranslate=no;Server=\\.\pipe\DB.196-
bb5f9dd884cf\sql\query
```

Comment: How are you testing for your temporary table?

Comment: if object_id('tempdb..#tablename') is not null drop table.  The stored procedures that are revealing this error are not using temp tables though - they're still using CTE's.  I'll add that detail to the post.

Comment: But CTEs with INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE aren't supported, so that could be your problem, right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - there are some stored procedures that don't have INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE statements in them.  For those SPs, I kept the CTE's.  When I run the SP's that have the CTE's at 100DWU, I get the error mentioned above

Comment: And if you use sub-queries instead of CTEs?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear about your experience with Azure SQL Data Warehouse. I believe this is a defect related to BIT data type handling for NOT NULL columns. Can you confirm that you have a BIT NOT NULL column (e.g., CREATE TABLE t1 (IsTrue BIT NOT NULL);)?

If so, a fix has been coded and is in testing for release. To mitigate this now, you can either switch to a TINY INT or remove the NOT NULL setting for the column.

Comment: I do not have a column of this data type.  If this were causing the issue, how would scaling the DW from 100 DWU to 500 DWU resolve it?

Comment: If you haven't already done so please raise a support ticket for this issue so it can be investigated properly.

Comment: Can you create a support ticket by following the instructions in the link below?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-create-support-ticket/

If you don't have a support plan (required to create a technical support case), please email the SQL Data Warehouse team directly at sqldwfeedback@microsoft.com and include your server name, database name, error message and the approximate timestamp of this error